# Hynniewtrep National Liberation Council: Listed by India from when to when?

Tags: india, terrorism

From when to when has the [Hynniewtrep National Liberation Council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hynniewtrep_National_Liberation_Council) been on [India's list of organizations declared as terrorist organizations](http://www.mha.gov.in/uniquepage.asp?Id_Pk=292)?

Wikipedia says it started on 16 November 2000 but the reference does not seem to support that theory.

It seems to be getting less active, and actually it is not on India's list anymore.

Question: When did they enter the list, and when did they leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was banned on [16 November 2000](http://www.satp.org/satporgtp/countries/india/states/meghalaya/terrorist_outfits/HNLC.HTM) and appeared on the list till [2011](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2011-01-14/guwahati/28379990_1_ulfa-leadership-arabinda-rajkhowa-chitraban-hazarika).

EDIT: Updated Wikipedia.